# video player - video.js - (Wait Until the Player is Ready) not working

Tags: javascript, video.js

having some trouble using the video.js (videojs.com)

this simple html was extracted from thier example at:
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/releases/download/v7.5.0/video-js-7.5.0.zip

For start, I just want the "Wait Until the Player is Ready" to work and get a "Hi" popup.
(https://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/api.html)

https://jsfiddle.net/a7pn0j28/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/7.0/video.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){        
            alert('hi')
            //var myPlayer = this;
            // EXAMPLE: Start playing the video.
            //myPlayer.play();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264" poster="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.png" data-setup="{}">
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>

</body>

</html>
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

When your script tag  in the head executes, the  video element doesn't exist yet. You could move the script to the end of the body.